# Can I add an outlet on the back side of a wall?

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet in the kitchen - How do I know if it's possible to install an outlet or two on the opposite side of the wall?  Also interested in running a few low voltage under cabinet lights.  What do I need to look for?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, There is not enough info for us to give you and informed answer. Your question is much to broad, you need to narrow it down to specifics and split it into two questions. Add as  much details as you can for better answers.

Comment: Does that existing outlet serve a kitchen countertop surface?  What room will the new outlets serve?